# Ставится ли запятая перед и

Tags: пунктуация

Известная фраза Черчилля:

> Вы выбрали бесчестье()и теперь получите войну.

Оригинал:

> You chose dishonour, and you will have war.

Ставится ли здесь запятая?

Мне кажется, что здесь она ставится. Но в википедии запятой нет.

Или возможны оба варианта?
Влияет ли слово "теперь" на постановку знака?

Answer (score 1):

В английском языке, насколько мне известно, запятые ставятся по иным правилам, нежели в русском языке. В переведенном на русский предложении нет необходимости ставить запятую перед одиночным союзом "и" , соединяющим однородные сказуемые. Конечно, во второй части предложения имеется некоторый дополнительный оттенок следствия, но правила таких нюансов не предусматривают для сложносочиненных предложений.

Answer (score 1):

Важное значение для смысла этой фразы и пунктуации имеет контекст. Если рассматривать её отдельно, может показаться, что здесь прямая причинно-следственная связь между выбором бесчестья и грядущей войной (выбрано бесчестье, и этим выбрана скорая война) - в этом случае можно поразмышлять о запятой. Однако перед этим сказано, что выбор делался "между" бесчестьем и войной. Это определяет смысл второй фразы: вопреки сделанному выбору, вы имеете и то, и другое. Поскольку в данном варианте перевода нет оборота "и... и" и оставлено одно подлежащее, то для передачи такого смысла запятой не нужно. Выбрали (и получили) бесчестье и в придачу получите войну. Слово "теперь" не должно этого менять.

Answer (score 1):

> Ставится ли здесь запятая?

Нет. В английском это сложносочиненное предложение, состоящее из двух полных простых:  с подлежащим и сказуемым в каждом. Так что там и по русским правилам нужна запятая. Но в русском варианте второго подлежащего нет.

> Или возможны оба варианта?

Не думаю. Вариант с запятой крайне сомнителен. Для этого надо убедить себя и других, что здесь не два однородных сказуемых, а сложносочиненное предложение из двух простых, второе из которых - определенно-личное (с восстанавливаемым подлежащим "ВЫ"). Грамматике формально не противоречит, но никаких веских причин выбрать именно эту трактовку я не вижу в принципе.  Разве что различие в грамматическом времени у первого и второго сказуемого, но это вполне допустимо и в рамках грамматического разбора с однородными сказуемыми.

> Влияет ли слово "теперь" на постановку знака?

Нет.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно запятая не ставится, так как считается, что это однородные сказуемые.

Но запятую можно поставить, если считать, что это сложное предложение, состоящее из двух определенно-личных предложений. И это было бы более правильным решением, так как по семантике это **неоднородные придаточные**, описывающие разные по времени ситуации, связанные причинно-следственными отношениями.

В то же время такое решение кажется нестандартным и может потребовать от автора объяснений.

Comment: Причинно-следственная связь здесь исключена предыдущей фразой: "у вас был выбор между войной и бесчестьем". Война была бы и при другом выборе, поэтому в логике рассматриванемой фразы она не является следствием выбора в пользу бесчестья.

Comment: Да, в этом случае (с учетом контекста) нет причинно-следственной связи, но отношения между предложениями всё равно неоднородные: об этом говорит наречие "теперь", а также разная семантика глаголов (выбрать и получить) и сопоставление ситуаций: хотели избежать войны, но все равно ее получили (союз "и" близок по значению к союзу "но"). Всё это склоняет к решению считать предложение сложным.

Comment: (Всё касается только варианта перевода:
"Вы выбрали бесчестье и теперь получите войну.")
Здесь нет двух разделённых суждений (подлежащее одно), и можно говорить только о формальной разнородности сказуемых. Семантически расхождение только по временам, поскольку "сделать" выбор и "получить" в нём заложенное - в данном случае это тождественные по смыслу действия: выбрали = получили бесчестье и получите войну. Но времена не требуют запятой (более очевидный пример): "вы были и останетесь недальновидными политиками".

Comment: Что касается слова "теперь". Без запятой это слово лишь уточняет разделение во времени выбора и грядущей войны. Но если поставить запятую, это создаст ложное впечатление  причинно-следственной связи: ", и теперь" будет восприниматься как "вследствие этого". В чём польза запятой, если она только препятствует правильному пониманию второй фразы (взятой отдельно от первой)?

Comment: Спасибо, я с большим интересом читаю ваши комментарии, у Вас оригинальный подход к грамматическим объяснениям. Но мне кажется, вы преувеличиваете возможности письма для выражения конкретных оттенков смысла. В данной теме разнообразная конкретика сводится к определению однородности глаголов-сказуемых. Если они однородны, то это простое предложение, если неоднородны - сложное.Различные факторы склоняют нас к одному или другому выводу. Мне кажется, что здесь описывается не одна, а две взаимообусловленные ситуации.

Comment: Я бы не  сказал, что две ситуации внутри второй фразы в авторском варианте взаимообусловлены. Ранее Вы справедливо обратили внимание, что случай нестандартный для русского понимания. В английском грамматически возможно отн. простое объединение совершенно разнородных суждений, на основе их действия в сторону общего вывода (сформулирован он или нет). В данном случае (два одинаковых подлежащих) раздельное действие двух суждений (недостойно + недальновидно) в пользу общего вывода (вы поступили плохо) лаконично подчёркнуто запятой (вне этой логики она не нужна, тем более, перед and).

Comment: Для объединения совсем разнородных фраз в английском есть спец. конструкции 'correlative conjunction' (здесь напр. 'not only did you... but /also/ you will'). В рамках данного варианта перевода можно только оценить, способствует запятая передаче исходного смысла, или нет. Ведь русская фраза стремится передать "английский смысл", чему наши правила могут и воспрепятствовать. "И теперь" создаёт некоторый уклон в сторону причинно-следственной связи. В моем восприятии, добавляемая перед этим запятая становится последней каплей, меняющей смысл в эту сторону - я в таких случаях поминаю Гиппократа :)

Comment: "И + теперь" попадается только в варианте перевода из "Википедии", которой свойственна тенденция к выверениям - с течением времени. Видимо, вызывал вопросы и канонический перевод с двумя подлежащими: "Вы выбрали бесчестье, теперь вы получите войну." Вероятно, все остальные варианты идут от него: слова "теперь" в оригинале нет. Третий характерный вариант отличается точкой на месте запятой. Если переводить заново, могу такое предложить: "Вы выбрали бесчестье, при этом вы получите и войну."

Comment: Да, хороший вариант, он лучше передает семантику высказывания.